# WPF: How to use views like ICollectionView and IEditableCollectionView

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol, collectionview, ieditablecollectionview

I understand the syntax but not how really to use it. It's clear in many basic scenarios but as soon as it get's a little bit advanced I start getting a headache.

For example there are many different views but often not clear wich one to use. Also should you use always just one or mix and match. Do you use the view as your itemssource for ItemsControls?

I'm gonna give a scenario. I have items from a database that I need to show info about in a app and also allow to edit and add new. The items form a hierarchy and the models are of different types. So the top level have children and they then have children.

I could show it in a TreeView or some itemscontrol. Problem here is I tend to bind to the children property of the root elements wich returns a List of chilren. Now the children aren't really inside a view, like I can't call editview.addnew() or filter the children straight away. Question is how do I ensure the children are also in a view and their children and so on. Should the model return a view, should I create a seperate view for each children type or even for each parent?

Another thing is if I'm allowing editing should I put the Collections straight into a IEditableCollectionView or wrap it in ICollectionView first (why is that better)?

Is there a good guide to using views that isn't just pure basics?